# GameObject transform with respect to local camera?

Tags: unity, camera, transformation

I'd like to recycle objects as they pass behind the camera frustum -- i.e, the plane of the local Z axis, orthogonal to the camera vector:  `Camera.main.transform.forward.`

Is there a nice method to test for the above case?  That is, "if a GameObject's location < local Z = 0 plane", we can know that it is behind the camera.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the methods in `MonoBehaviour`, `OnBecameVisible ()` and `OnBecameInvisible ()`, they are called whenever a gameObject becomes invisible or visible to the game camera.

For example:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnBecameInvisible () {
        GetComponent <Renderer> ().enabled = false;
    }

    void OnBecameVisible () {
        GetComponent <Renderer> ().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

I also think the cameras in Unity already cull objects by default automatically, you might not even need to do this at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
bool IsBehind(Vector3 worldPosition, Transform observer) {
    return Vector3.Dot(worldPosition - observer.position, observer.forward) < 0f;
}
```

This dot product computes the signed distance of the provided world position along the observer's forward axis. If it's negative, the position is behind the observer.